# Can every reducible multivariate polynomial be partitioned into product of univariate polynomials of algebraically independent elements?

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-complexity

Lets say we define a reducible multivariate $f \in \mathbb{F}[x_1,...,x_n]$ to be partionable by $y_1,...,y_r \in \mathbb{F}[x_1,...,x_n]$ iff
\begin{equation}
f(x_1,,,,.x_n) = f_1(y_1)\cdot f_2(y_2) \cdot \cdot \cdot f_r(y_r)
\end{equation}
where $f_i(y_i) \in \mathbb{F}[y_i]$.
Can we always partition a polynomial by algebraically independent elements in a non-trivial way (i.e. not partitioning f by itself)? Can you also link references to work done on this problem?

Comment: I may be missing something, but isn’t the answer obviously *no*, e.g. for irreducible polynomials, or for polynomials that are already univariate?

Comment: The question isn't very well framed. You are right; for irreducible polynomials and univariate, we can't do anything better than trivial. The interesting case would be multivariate and reducible polynomials. We can try to partition by irreducible elements, but I don't think they would be algebraically independent.

Comment: Since $\mathbb F[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is a UFD, you can’t do better than what the prime factorization gives. E.g., $(x+y)(x+y+1)$ is multivariate and reducible, but its only nontrivial partition is to $x+y$ and $x+y+1$, which are not algebraically independent.

Comment: But in the above example if we consider $x+y$ as an algebraic variable the polynomial reduces to a univariate. In general can we collect the different factors that can be expressed as univariates in some variable

Comment: This makes no sense. *Every* polynomial $f$ reduces to a univariate polynomial in some variable (namely, take $f$ itself as an algebraic variable).

Comment: You are right my question is not well defined. I am unable to clearly describe what I am truly getting at. When I have a clearer picture I'll add a new question or edit this question.The discussion was quite helpful though :)

Comment: Look, I have no idea what you want to use the property in the question for, but there is no sensible way in which it would “always” hold. With a bit of algebra, you can easily characterize *which* polynomials $f$ have such a nontrivial partition: exactly those that have an irreducible factor $g$ such that $g$ is algebraically independent from $f$.

Comment: Probably you are right thanks

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding something, the univariate case of your question seems similar to [polynomial decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_decomposition).